# AppStore Submission Issue

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I am submitting my first iOS app to the app store and I am having an issue that I do not know how to resolve. Here is a recap of what I have done:

I went to the iOS dev center, created a provisioning and distribution profile (for the app store), and uploaded them to Xcode. Then I went onto iTunes connect and completed the entire application.  In itunes Connect, the app status reads as 'ready for upload'. So I go back into Xcode, and do an archive using the profiles I made for this project. I select validation and I get the following error message over and over again: "Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode." So I double checked that my bundle identifier is correct in my application, and it is. So now what? Can anyone give me a clue as to any newbie mistakes I could have made in this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be many things, are you sure your provisioning profiles are set correctly in the build settings? If things still go wrong, follow these 2 tutorials, good luck :)

[Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

[Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)

Comment: Thanks, I found the step that I missed in part 2. Apparently I missed the selection of one radio button and the clue was that the app status in itunes connect should be "waiting for upload" rather than "ready for upload."

Comment: Perfect, it's always tricky the first time, glad it helped and good luck with the approval process!