# iTunes Connect binary status "Created"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, watchkit, submission

There is a new App with WatchKit extension that I am helping to publish. Xcode validates it and submits it successfully to iTunes Connect.

The problem is that there it stays with the status "Created" without any change for several days now. I have tried Application Loader, Xcode 6.3.1, different build numbers with no luck.

[image]

Something strange is that we also uploaded another app with the same characteristics that doesn't have this problem and their status clears in a matter of minutes.

[image]

Same account, same proceedings, WatchKit extension, entitlements, etc. Even this one has some missing version information so it shows warning signs. But still builds can be selected from the version tab and it shows TestFlight related information.

The only difference I can see in iTunes Connect is that in the App with problems the BundleID can still be changed. But I guess it is due to no binary clearing its status yet.

[image]

The last difference I can recall between the two apps is that Xcode did create the distribution provisioning profiles for the working one, but I had to manually create them for the problematic one. Also Xcode seemed to skip profiles for the watchkitapp which I added manually to both with no changes. I have double checked all the profiles settings one by one.

I have checked BundleID's, certificates, cleaned, deleted DerivedData, waited for days, checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326207/1049134) including the (now old) linked tutorials to make sure I am not missing anything. The only thing that is not present anymore from the tutorials is the "Ready to Upload Binary" button now missing from iTunes Connect. Also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825415/itunes-connect-binary-status-created) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143661/new-itunes-connect-interface-should-it-immediately-be-seen-on-prerelease).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it was an iTunes Connect bug. I did the following, not sure which step fixed the issue:

- Changed the BundleID in Xcode for the app and WatchKit extension and app.
- Deselected team and selected it again to make Xcode generate Development profiles.
- Manually created and downloaded Distribution profiles, WatchKit app doesn't seem to need one.
- Changed the BundleID for my app in iTunes Connect. I could do this because no binary was successfully uploaded before.
- Changed build number and uploaded binary using Xcode.

After some minutes the binary status got cleared and all previous binaries disappeared from the list.

I can now select the binary from the version tab.

---

I just noticed status emails that were being sent to my Apple ID's secondary email:

> Invalid Icon - The watch application contains an icon file with an alpha channel. Icons should not have an alpha channel.

Which was probably the reason of the binaries not being processed. It is still an iTunes Connect bug that this passed Xcode's validation and didn't shown an invalid binary status in the prerelease list.

Comment: apple decided to redesign this whole dashboard for no reason this created a lot of bugs

Answer (score 0):

I too have same issue, but i uploaded same binary by changing the Build number and it worked.